# How do I populate my form with the data sent by a user after a GET request in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

```
def index(request):
    if len(request.GET) == 0:
        form = FlightSearchForm()
    else:
        arr = request.GET.get('arrival_airport')
        dep = request.GET.get('departure_airport')
        form = FlightSearchForm({'departure_airport': dep,'arrival_airport': arr})
    return render(request, 'app1/index.html', {'form': form})
```

What I want to do is create a form that would allow users to search for a flight, so I need them to use GET request. The problem is I don't know how to make their search appear in the fields after they go to their specific url (with all the details they searched for). It worked with a POST request in the past, but obviously I can't use it in this case.

```
class FlightSearchForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.departure_airport = kwargs.pop('departure_airport')
        self.arrival_airport = kwargs.pop('arrival_airport')
        super.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    departure_airport = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    arrival_airport = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I tried something like that but it didn't help. Now it shouts that there is a keyerror, which doesn't exist. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a form without the extra logic for `departure_airlport` and `arrival_airport`, so simply:

```
class FlightSearchForm(forms.Form):
    departure_airport = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    arrival_airport = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    # no __init__
```

Then you can use the data as [**`initial=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#initial-form-values) data:

```
def index(request):
    if not request.GET:
        form = FlightSearchForm()
    else:
        arr = request.GET.get('arrival_airport')
        dep = request.GET.get('departure_airport')
        form = FlightSearchForm(initial={'departure_airport': dep,'arrival_airport': arr})
    return render(request, 'app1/index.html', {'form': form})
```

another option is to pass `request.GET` directly as data into the form:

```
def index(request):
    if not request.GET:
        form = FlightSearchForm()
    else:
        form = FlightSearchForm(request.GET)
    return render(request, 'app1/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I tried all those but they didn't work. But hey I found the real problem after 7 hours ;) For all interested in the future: I used this in my form:<input type="text" name="arrival_airport" maxlength="100" class="form-control" placeholder="Arrival airport">. So when I wanted to use "arrival_airport" from request.get.get it was there but the new form that got created afterwards was not the the actual django form. So instead it is better to use: {{form.arrival_airport}}. Thank you anyway for ur answer!